# erlang: gen-server and state

Tags: erlang, state, gen-server

As an exercise to test my understanding of sequential Erlang I wrote a simple-minded html tag editor.

It maintains a current position in the text, e.g. edit state, in a record like this:

```
-record(ed_txt, {a=[], b=[], c=[]).
```

...where a holds text above the current paragraph, b holds the current paragraph, and c holds text below the current paragraph.

It is called like this:

```
tag(App, FileName) ->
   {ok, File1} = get_file(App, FileName),
   {ok, File2} = file_to_paragraphs(File1),
   {ok, Record} = create_record(File2),
   ....

tag(Record) ->
   {ok, InputTuple} = get_input(Record), % gets edit command
   ...
   do(Command, Record)
```

The function do/2 is recursive function that looks like this:

```
   do("h", Record)    -> tag(help(Record));
   do("down", Record) -> tag(down(Record));
   do("up",Record)    -> tag(up(Record));
   do("h1", Record)   -> tag(wrap("H1", Record));
   ...
   do("quit", Record) -> {ok, quit(Record)};
   do(_, Record)      -> tag(Record).
```

Now I'd like to turn this module into an OTP gen-server, but realize that I don't really understand how to maintain state.

I created a state record:

```
-record(state, {app, filename, a=[], b=[], c=[]}).
```

My thought is to use a one-to-one supervisor so each user is working in his/her own process, ditch the edit loop, and use handle_call (or handle_cast) to call the respective
edit functions.

But what confuses me is this:

As long as the process is running, presumably user state is maintained in the process, but both handle_call and handle_cast take State as a parameter and return State.

Does this mean that I also have to maintain state for each user OUTSIDE of their respective processes, in ets perhaps?

Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: The state is kept between calls. The state you return in your handle_call function is the state you get in the next call to handle_call. So not, you don't need to keep it outside the process yourself. look this http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-April/057777.html

Comment: But you should do your editor client side and use a process only to save the text in memory and/or restore/save from DB

Comment: See this anser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166038/implementing-a-turing-machine-in-erlang/20168405#20168405 which I think answers most of your questions.

Comment: Thanks all for help. Had to do some experimenting, but think I see the light. I have read everything I can find on the web and in the books re: gen-server, but there are subtleties that, to me at least, are not all that clear. I still need more experience before I can articulate them. Niahoo: you may be right re: editing on the client side, but I'm following a whimsey that may or may not pan out.